# OpenGL back and front buffer - counting and adjusting the number of red pixels before displaying to screen

Tags: opengl, buffer, framebuffer

I'm writing a function that reads the number of red pixels on the left and right halves of the screen, it makes adjustments while the difference between the number of red pixels falls outside of a threshold. I'm having trouble with the buffers (back and front) because when I finally swap to the front buffer, it dynamically draws all changes I made in the loop meant for the back buffer (as though changes got queued) but I only want the final one drawn to screen. In pseudocode,

```
do {
draw scene to back buffer
read number of left, right red pixels
if (abs(left-right)>threshold) {
//some function to jitter objects in the scene
}
else done=true,
}while(!done);
draw to front buffer
```

Here is some C++/OpenGL code:

```
do{     
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
display(0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
display(1);

 redsleft = 0;
 redsright = 0;

glReadBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);

glReadPixels(0, 0, resolution.first, resolution.second, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frameBuffer);
for (int j = 0; j < resolution.first*resolution.second * 4; j += 4){
    if (frameBuffer[j]>0 && frameBuffer[j + 1] == 0 && frameBuffer[j + 2] == 0 && frameBuffer[j + 3] > 0)
            {


                if (j % 4 == 0 && i == 0)

                {

                    int redX = (j / 4) % resolution.first;

                    int redY = j / 4 / resolution.first;

                    if (redX < resolution.first / 2)
                        redsleft++;


                    else
                        redsright++;

                }

            }


        }
        //if abs redsleft-redsright is above threshold, call function to adjust 
        //else done

    }   
}

}while (!done);

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_LEFT);
display(0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK_RIGHT);
display(1);

glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
```

Any ideas?
I've been trying also things like glFlush(), glClear(), but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: To me, this question is completely unclear. What exactly do you want to achieve, and which results do you get? What does `display()` actually do? How do you deal with the clearings of the buffers involved? " it dynamically draws all changes I made in the loop meant for the back buffer (as though changes got queued)" suggests that you just draw everything on top of each other to the back buffer, and you shouldn't be surprised to see all of that after you swapped that to the front.

Comment: I think you are right that the problem is that the back buffers are not clearing . I tried glClear but didn't clear everything for me and I'm wondering if I'm missing something,  I'll try again something  and I'll get back to you thank you for your help